# Uniform distribution over the unit circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose that $U$ and $V$ are two independent uniform $(-1,1)$ random variables.

Any hints on how I can show that their conditional distribution, given $U^2 +V^2<1$ is given by the uniform distribution over the unit circle, namely

$$f_{U,V|U^2+V^2<1} (u,v|w<1) =1/{\pi}, \quad u^2+v^2<1$$

Both an intuitive and a rigorous dervation would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I really need to not multitask while commenting...was initially writing out the comment with the variable being distributed over the circumference, which wasn't what you were asking or implied by the question, and then didn't correct it when I posted, so it was just a mixed up mess :-\

Comment: There is also a unit-*disk*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the conditional probability formula $P(X \in A| X \in B) = \frac{P(X \in A \cap B)}{P(X \in B)}$ when $P(X \in B) > 0$.

Now take $X = (U, V), B = \{(u,v): u^2 + v^2 <1\}$. Let A be a measurable subset 0f $(-1, 1) \times (-1,1)$, since $P(X \in B) = \frac{m(B)}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4}$, we have $P(X \in A | X\in B) = \frac{\frac{m(A\cap B)}{4}}{\frac{\pi}{4}} = \frac{m(A \cap B)}{\pi}$. When A is a subset of B it's $\frac{m(A)}{\pi}$, which means uniform distribution ovr B.

More generally, if X is a uniform distribution over $B \subset R^n$, the conditional distribution knowing that X is in $A \subset B$ is the uniform distribution over A. This property helps to simulate some kinds of uniform distributions. For example, we want to simulate a uniform distribution in $x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$, then we could simulate a sequence of  uniform distributions in $[-1,1] \times [-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}]$ and take from the sequence the first point in $x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$ as the simulation result.

Comment: What I do not understand is why $$P[x^2 + y^2 <1]=\pi$$

Comment: Because $(U, V)$ is uniform over $(-1, 1)\times (-1, 1)$, then by definition the probability that it belongs to a subset of $(-1, 1)\times (-1, 1)$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ times the Lebesgue measure of the subset, which in your case equals to $\pi$

Comment: I do not know much about measure theory at this point, so what is the Lebesque measure of the subset?

Comment: Roughly speaking in dimension 2, you can take Lebesque measure of a set as its area, and the area of the unit circle is $\pi$

Comment: But doesn't that mean that the probability is $\pi /4$? $1/4 \times  \pi$

Comment: Ah, I understand your question, sorry I made a mistake in the response, I will fix it.

Comment: Hope now it's Ok :)

Comment: Now it is the numerator I am trying to understand. Why did you divide by 4?

Comment: Since $X$ is uniform over B, the probability that X is in A is equal to the area of A divided by the area of B. 4 is the area of $(-1,1) \times (-1,1)$

Answer (score 1):

The original density of $(U,V)$ is constant on $\left(-1,1\right)^{2}$. Actually it equals $\frac{1}{4}$ since integration over that area must result in
$1$. The density of $(U,V)$ under condition $U^{2}+V^{2}<1$ is constant as well. There is only one choice then: $\pi^{-1}$. This because integration over that area must result in $1$ again.

> $\int\int_{A}p_{U,V}\left(u,v\right)dudv=P\left\{ \left(U,V\right)\in A\right\} =1$

This for $A=\left(-1,1\right)^{2}$ in the original case and for $A'=\left\{ \left(u,v\right)\mid u^{2}+v^{2}<1\right\} $
in the conditional case. Both times with a constant density $p$.

Answer (score 0):

We note that

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(U< x,V< y|U^2+V^2<1)&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(U< x,V< y,U^2+V^2<1)}{\mathbb{P}(U^2+V^2<1)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(U< x,V<y)}{\mathbb{P}(U^2+V^2<1)}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{P}(U< x)\mathbb{P}(V<y)}{\mathbb{P}(U^2+V^2<1)}
\end{aligned}$$

Now let's apply total probability law to calculate

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(U^2+V^2<1)&=\int_{-1}^1\mathbb{P}(u^2+V^2<1)f_U(u)du=\int_{-1}^1\mathbb{P}(V^2<1-u^2)\frac{1}{2}du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\mathbb{P}(|V|<\sqrt{1-u^2})du=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\mathbb{P}(-\sqrt{1-u^2}<V<\sqrt{1-u^2})du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\left(\mathbb{P}(V<\sqrt{1-u^2})-\mathbb{P}(V<-\sqrt{1-u^2})\right)du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\left(\mathbb{P}(V<\sqrt{1-u^2})-\mathbb{P}(V<-\sqrt{1-u^2})\right)du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}+1}{2}-\frac{-\sqrt{1-u^2}+1}{2}\right)du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-u^2}du\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore

$$
\mathbb{P}(U< x,V< y|U^2+V^2<1)=\frac{\frac{x+1}{2}\frac{y+1}{2}}{\frac{\pi}{4}}
$$

And finally the desired density function is

$$
f_{U,V|U^2+V^2<1}(x,v|U^2+V^2<1)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{(x+1)/2(y+1)/2}{\pi/4}=\frac{1}{\pi}
$$